# How to make a smooth walk "animation"

Tags: javascript

In my game I have a player speed variable (`speed = 10`) and if I am pressing "a" or "d" the player moves to the left or to the right (`player.x += speed` or `player.x -= 10`). The problem now is when I am increasing the movement speed to 20 or higher the player jumps to this position and then I don't have a smooth walk animation.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: If the player moves more than 1 pixel per frame the only option for him is to `jump`. You can not add an intermediate frame between two movements, but you can add some transparent trails so that the jump is not that obvious, but more like a motion blur effect.

Comment: Please include a code sample in your question

Comment: Not really saying how to fix it but using jQuery makes animating and translating things really simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally you specify speed as distance per time

e.g. speed = 10 could mean 10 pixel per second

what you would have to do then is to iterate many times per second (60 times is often used) and check if the player has pressed a direction button. If so, you move the player not per 10 pixel, but only per 10/60 pixel (you have to store decimal values in the player position)

if you repeat this 60 times (the player has pressed the button a whole second), the character will be moved by the 10 pixel you specified

Comment: Thanks this was the solution :)